# Webdriver with PhantomJS works in terminal shell but not in PyCharm on Mac OS

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, pycharm

I have used brew to install selenium(webdriver):

```
$ phantomjs --version
2.1.1
```

Then, I try to run this code in pycharm but get error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
if __name__ == '__main__':
   driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
   driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/")
   print driver.current_url
```

There is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/haomao/pythonVir/workspace/tutorial/tutorial/url_judge.py", line 166, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
  File "/Users/haomao/pythonVir/envt1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/haomao/pythonVir/envt1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

But when I tried the same code in terminal and it worked.

```
(envt1) haomaodeMacBook-Pro:~ haomao$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/")
>>> print driver.current_url
https://www.amazon.com/
>>>
```

I have no idea about this question and searched in google ,it told me I need to add the path to the PhantomJS() like this *webdriver.PhantomJS(path)*. However I don't know the location of the phantomjs. Help me if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance!

> June 23rd

I find the path of phantomjs, '/usr/local/phantomjs' and add it to the code like webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/phantomjs').

But I need to change this code when I take the project to Linux, are there other ways?